If my landlord goes to jail, can I just go on living on the land without paying rent?
Say that Larry the Landlord is renting out a residence to Terry the Tenant.
Larry gets taken out of the picture somehow (maybe he committed a crime and is in jail for a long time, or maybe he died with no will, etc.).
Can Terry just go on living like a king in the residence without paying rent? If Larry happens to come back some time later (perhaps after finishing his jail sentence), can he reasonably demand Terry pay every last month's rent?

Why do you think so?

No Judgement would stipulate that
Terry's contract stipulates to pay Larry for the right to live there.
The verdict against the landlord does not take away his right to receive rent or payment from his properties. Even if Larry the Landlord dies, Terry has to pay into Larry's account. Somebody is entitled to the rent, even if Terry doesn't know who. If no heir can be found, then the one entitled is not Terry, but the state.
As such, Terry's contract stands, to pay rent to live there.
